# webgrind not showing function names or file source

Tags: linux, profiling, xdebug-profiler, webgrind

I'm trying to profile a web application with xDebug and Webgrind since I'm doing it in a remote Linux server. For some weird reason it doesn't show call names or file source. I was suspecting that there might be some kind problem with readying the script files (not sure if it's doing it) but giving target folders 777 didn't make any difference. Does anybody have a clue where I'm failing?

Thanx!

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The webgrind version found on google code does not work for xDebug 2.3.
Here is a fork that works: [webgrind](https://github.com/michaelschiller/webgrind)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 24h later:

Seems that webcache grind doesn't support cachegrind file function compression feature that was introduced in xDebug 2.3 (released 2015). The latest webgrind was released ~2008-2009 so makes sens that it doesn't work. The same applies to WinCacheGrind client. Currently seems that only Windows cachegrind analyzer is [qCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/) and linux client [kCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)

When I maange to find some free time I'll fork the project and make it compatible with compression.

Comment: Don, it looks like @Vincent Fenet has forked webgrind, perhaps you could mark his answer as correct.

Comment: Sure thing, forgot it since it was done quite a lot later.